# openshift template update not instantly shown in web console

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am using origin 3.9 (v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657).

I am trying to add an variable to an existing template in `openshift` namespace. This update is successful. I can verify it through `oc process`. But the update is not shown in web console instantly. It takes several minutes to take effect.

Not sure if it is due to some sort of cache. Where can I find the configurations for web console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following link is helpful, the resync interval is 15m as default.

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/service-catalog/issues/1086